# Pandas: append row to DataFrame with multiindex in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I have a DataFrame with a multiindex in the columns and would like to use dictionaries to append new rows.

Let's say that each row in the DataFrame is a city. The columns contains "distance" and "vehicle". And each cell would be the percentage of the population that chooses this vehicle for this distance.

I'm constructing an index like this:

```
index_tuples=[]

for distance in ["near", "far"]:
    for vehicle in ["bike", "car"]:
        index_tuples.append([distance, vehicle])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_tuples, names=["distance", "vehicle"])
```

Then I'm creating a dataframe:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(index=["city"], columns = index)
```

The structure of the dataframe looks good. Although pandas has added Nans as default values ?

[image: layout of the dataframe]

Now I would like to set up a dictionary for the new city and add it:

```
my_home_city = {"near":{"bike":1, "car":0},"far":{"bike":0, "car":1}}
dataframe["my_home_city"] = my_home_city
```

But this fails:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Here is the complete [error message](https://pastebin.com/Qn4Fr4se) (pastebin)

**UPDATE:**

Thank you for all the good answers. I'm afraid I've oversimplified the problem in my example. Actually my index is nested with 3 levels (and it could become more).

So I've accepted the universal answer of converting my dictionary into a list of tuples. This might not be as clean as the other approaches but works for any multiindex setup.

Comment: I think the keys of the diction need to be tuples, e.g., `{('near', 'bike'): 1, ('near', 'car'): 0 ...}`

Comment: side note: checkout `pandas.MultiIndex.from_product`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multi index is a `list` of `tuple` , we just need to modify your `dict` ,then we could directly assign the value

```
d = {(x,y):my_home_city[x][y] for x in my_home_city for y in my_home_city[x]}
df.loc['my_home_city',:]=d
df
Out[994]: 
distance     near       far     
vehicle      bike  car bike  car
city          NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
my_home_city    1    0    0    1
```

More Info

```
d
Out[995]: 
{('far', 'bike'): 0,
 ('far', 'car'): 1,
 ('near', 'bike'): 1,
 ('near', 'car'): 0}

df.columns.values
Out[996]: array([('near', 'bike'), ('near', 'car'), ('far', 'bike'), ('far', 'car')], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can append to you dataframe like this:

```
my_home_city = {"near":{"bike":1, "car":0},"far":{"bike":0, "car":1}}
dataframe.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_home_city).unstack().rename('my_home_city'))
```

Output:

```
distance     near       far     
vehicle      bike  car bike  car
city          NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
my_home_city    1    0    0    1
```

The trick is to create the dataframe row with `from_dict` then `unstack` to get structure of your original dataframe with multiindex columns then `rename` to get index and `append`.

Or if you don't want to create the empty dataframe first you can use this method to create the dataframe with the new data.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_home_city).unstack().rename('my_home_city').to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
              far     near    
             bike car bike car
my_home_city    0   1    1   0
```

**Explained:**

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_home_city)

      far  near
bike    0     1
car     1     0
```

Now, let's unstack to create multiindex and get to that new dataframe into the structure of the original dataframe.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_home_city).unstack()

far   bike    0
      car     1
near  bike    1
      car     0
dtype: int64
```

We use rename to give that series a name which becomes the index label of that dataframe row when appended to the original dataframe.

```
far   bike    0
      car     1
near  bike    1
      car     0
Name: my_home_city, dtype: int64
```

Now if you converted that series to a frame and transposed it would look very much like a new row, however, there is no need to do this because, Pandas does intrinsic data alignment, so appending this series to the dataframe will auto-align and add the new dataframe record.

```
dataframe.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_home_city).unstack().rename('my_home_city'))
distance     near       far     
vehicle      bike  car bike  car
city          NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
my_home_city    1    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you even need to initialise an empty dataframe. With your `d`, I can get your desired output with `unstack` and a transpose:

```
pd.DataFrame(d).unstack().to_frame().T

   far     near    
  bike car bike car
0    0   1    1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your empty dataframe using `MultiIndex.from_product`.

```
distances = ['near', 'far']
vehicles = ['bike', 'car']
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([distances, vehicles]), 
                  index=pd.Index([], name='city'))
```

Your dictionary results in a square matrix (distance by vehicle), so unstack it (which will result in a Series), then convert it into a dataframe row by calling (`to_frame`) using the relevant city name and transposing the column into a row.

```
>>> df.append(pd.DataFrame(my_home_city).unstack().to_frame('my_home_city').T)
              far     near    
             bike car bike car
city                          
my_home_city    0   1    1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to all of the answers, this is just another(maybe not too different) simple example, represented in a more reproducible way :

```
import itertools as it
from IPython.display import display # this is just for displaying output purpose
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

col_1, col_2 = ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']
arr_size = len(col_2)
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([col_1, col_2])
tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)
display(tmp_df)

for s in range(3):# no of rows to add to tmp_df
    tmp_dict = {x : [np.random.random_sample(1)[0] for i in range(arr_size)] for x in range(arr_size)}
    tmp_ser = pd.Series(it.chain.from_iterable([tmp_dict[x] for x in tmp_dict]), index=col)
    #  display(tmp_dict, tmp_ser)
    tmp_df = tmp_df.append(tmp_ser[tmp_df.columns], ignore_index=True)

display(tmp_df)
```

Some things to note about above:

- The number of items to add should always match `len(col_1)*len(col_2)`, that is the product of element lengths your multi-index is made from.
- `list(it.chain.from_iterable([[2, 3], [4, 5]]))` simply does this [2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 0):

#### try this workaround

- append to dict
- then convert to pandas data frame
- at the very last step select desired columns to create multi-index with set_index()

```
d = dict()
for g in predictor_types:
    for col in predictor_types[g]:
        tot = len(ames) - ames[col].count()
        if tot:
            d.setdefault('type',[]).append(g)
            d.setdefault('predictor',[]).append(col)
            d.setdefault('missing',[]).append(tot)
pd.DataFrame(d).set_index(['type','predictor']).style.bar(color='DodgerBlue')
```